# MassAssignmentException _token - Saving users and tasks

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 5.5.22`.
I am having users and tasks in my db. My tasks have the following schema:

```
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My users model looks like the following

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function task()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
}
```

I would like to store the task from a user in the database. See below the store method I have tried:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'newTaskName' => 'required|min:3|max:190',
    ]);

    Auth::user()->task()->Create($request->all()); //here I get the error
    Session::flash('success', 'New task has been successfully added.');

    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

However, I get the following error at this line `Auth::user()->task()->Create($request->all());`:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException _token
```

Any suggestions why the request is not safed properly?

Comment: As it says: mass assignment is not set on your Task model for prop '_token'. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment And it should not be because $request->all() will include the csrf_token send with the request. Change that line to $request->only(['prop1', 'prop2]);

Comment: share `Task` model also ? Specially `$fillable` value ?

Comment: $request->all() works for me in any way.. create() is reflect only the field in fillable.. if not.. it will ignore.. show your Task model

Comment: @user2486 My task model is empty.

Comment: @mrquad : it is needed to use `$fillable` in model to use `create` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `DB`

```
$insertData = [
   "name" => $request->name,
   "user_id" => \Auth::id()
];

DB::table('tasks')->insert($insertData);
```

OR if you have model created as `Task`

```
$task = new Task($insertData);
$task->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `->except()` method instead of `all()`:

```
Auth::user()->task()->create($request->except('_token'));
```

Comment: @user2486 OP haven't posted the `Task` model so I assumed he has `fillable` in it. And yes, you need to have `fillable` in a model to make `create()` work.

Answer (score 0):

at Task Model add this line :

```
protected $guarded = ['_token'];
```